String not evaluated correctly during Write-Host
When printing, I would assume that whatever is evaluated in the "Write-Host" command would be printed on screen. However, when executing this code on PS 5.1, the print is empty. The cursor moves to the right, but I guess $i++ is not being evaluated correctly?
$i = 1; $time = 1;
while($true){
  Write-Host "$($i++) " -NoNewLine;
  Start-Sleep $time
}

Is this correct behavior? How can I generate the output 1 2 3 4 5 6 (...)?
Also tried "$(++$i) " as an approach, but same result.

$i++ doesn't produce output by itself. You can use parentheses: $(($i++)) to get output from that expression. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#grouping-operator--
